# Connecting 100 devices via blue tooth to multiple pcs

Tags: bluetooth

I've been asked to create a system where by 100+ bar code readers are connected wirelessly to 2 or more access points (pcs).  The bar code readers I've seen so far all use blue tooth as the wireless connection so I was wondering is it possible to have a set up where all 100+ bar code devices can connect to a single PC?

Its also likely that the system will be used in multiple locations so multiple hub pcs might exist in which case the bar code readers should just connect to the nearest one.

Its this a supported set up for blue tooth or would I need to look at some other way of connecting all these devices.